# using ssh with stat command bash

Tags: bash, awk, ssh, escaping, stat

I am trying to run this:

```
ssh $server_name@$host_IP "for wal in $server_wal_archive_dir/*
    do
            fileD=$(ssh $server_name@$host_IP stat -c %y \"\$wal\" | awk \'{print \$1,\$2}\')

            fileDate=$(date --date=\"$fileD\" +%s)

            if [ $currentDate -gt $fileDate ]
            then
                     ssh $server_name@$host_IP rm $wal
            fi
    done"
```

But it shows me this message:

```
awk: '{print
awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
stat: cannot stat `': No such file or directory
date: invalid date`""'
```

I know date error is because no value in $fileD

I have tried to figure it out escaping the single quotes but no luck, what is my mistake?

Thanks in advance

David

Comment: Why wouldn't you just create this as a script on the remote server?

Comment: Wait, why are you connecting to a server and then telling the server to connect back to itself twice?

Comment: For anything more than a simple one-liner, you are better off writing a script copy to the remote server, rather than trying to separate which expansions need to happen locally and which need to happen remotely.

Comment: I need to collect some files from server to store them safe in another server, I can not install anything in the remote server,  I use ssh twice because the first ssh it is only used in the "for" and the second one is to stat command.

Comment: Yes, but `ssh localhost stat` offers no advantage over just `stat`; in fact, it is hugely wasteful as well as error-prone.